# Wordpress, Javascript and parse.com, how to include?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, parse-platform

I am trying to use javascript to call an existing Parse.com database in my wordpress site.
First of all I included the two required scripts (the JQuery and Parse itself) in the header, and they are listed in the dependencies, using both the classical method of the `<script>` tags and the `wp_enqueue/register`.

Then, to include the Parse scripts I am just pasting the code suggested by Parse in a page (text view)

```
    <script type="text/javascript>
    <!--
    Parse.initialize("myappbla", "myappbla");
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", "my name");
    user.set("password", "my pass");
    user.set("email", "email@example.com");
    user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
    });
    //--></script>
```

Even if I can see the jquery and the parse scripts are called in the sources, the code doesnt work at all as if I didn't put it at all and there is no change in my database.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I solved the problem: I was not calling the code wrapping it in a function as it has to be done. I defined a function for this code in the header file of wordpress and then I executed it inside my wordpress page and now it works.

Comment: does the code work in a standalone html page? SOunds strange that you say you use both `wp_enqueue` and regular tags

Comment: No, it is in a Wordpress page inside the template. I also tried including the code into a template.php file but still doesnt work. Regarding your question, I used the regular tags in the footer and the wp_enqueue in the header just to be sure (but the tags in the footer are the ones working I guess)

Comment: get it working in a standalone page first

Comment: This code should work in a standalone page, as it is copypasted by Parse.com website (and other javascripts without calls to Parse are also working fine on my wordpress page)

Comment: update, it doesn't work at all, not even in a standalone page

Comment: read the PArse API docs regarding users, not sure what permissions are exposed to add new users but at least you know it's nothing to do with wordpress integration

Comment: Now I solved the problem, the script had to be wrapped in a function in the header file of wordpress and then called within the page text view. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to wrap the code into a function in the header file of wordpress and then call the function within the page.